# How to disable LSPosed, eventually any notification that cannot be disabled using settings?

Tags: notifications, lsposed

I have rooted herolte phone, Lineage OS 19.1, Android 12, and I would like to ask, how can I force disable any notification that cannot be disabled by default in settings.

Especially the LSPosed one which is really annoying, but I cannot create the shortcut (because I use an UI which does not support shortcuts) which is essential to be able to disable the notification in the app.

Consequently, my question is, how could I disable any notification or at least the LSPosed one?
Thanks for answer.